# Kitzur Hilchot Arba' Minim

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

When I went to purchase my arba' minim for Sukkot this year, I realised that I was ignorant of most of the halachot. I told myself that I would learn these halachot before next Sukkot בלי נדר but I was unsure where to learn. My first thought was Shulchan 'Aruch. Although I would love to learn the halachot with more attention to detail, I thought realistically to myself that a pamphlet/small book would likely be better to study for this.

With that in mind, I was wondering if there is a sefer which is effectively a קצור הלחות ד׳ מינים, either in Hebrew or Hebrew and English translations.(The only thing I saw which fit the קצור qualification was an English-only Eider pamphlet. This was exactly what I was looking for, except for the fact that I want to learn the halachot in Hebrew). Ideally, it should have illustrations, considering that the form of the species relates to its kashrut. It should contain base-line requirements as well as hiddurim.

Is such a volume available? If so, if it is only available digitally, is there a print-on-demand option?

Comment: [This sefer](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578193806.html) is all in English, so it doesn't fit your criteria, but I've heard great things about it. artscroll.com/Books/9781578193806.html I, too, realized how ignorant of hilchos arba minim I was

Comment: You could try any number of these seforim: http://www.nehora.com/kitzur-dinai-arbas-haminim/, http://www.nehora.com/arbeh-minim-lmehadrin/, http://www.nehora.com/lekicha-tama-the-lulav-and-esrog-buying-guide/, http://www.nehora.com/the-four-minim-a-practical-illustrated-guide/. Some are out of stock, but will probably be back in stock when Succos rolls around again next year. Or you could call them or shop elsewhere if you like what you see..

Comment: I used to have a small brochure on just this area published by Yeshiva Darchei Torah of Far Rockaway, NY, about 5 years ago. I'll see if I can contact them if you wish.

Comment: @ezra I have the artscroll one from your first comment and it is indeed very good, practical, well illustrated - recommended - only challenge for OP is that it is English only with Hebrew words interspeded